# Java Pattern Design

Tags: java, drawing

I am trying to make this pattern on java:

```
*******
 ******
  *****
   ****
    ***
     **
      *
```

However, till now I have only been able to produce this code:

```
public  class Pattern
{
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    int height = 7;
    for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++ ) {
      for (int j = 0; j <= i ; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
 }
```

This code can only produce this image:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
```

What part of the code should I change to be able to produce the first image?

Thanks for your help,
I apologize if this is a wrong question
but I would much appreciate the help.

Comment: Reverse the outer loop limits: for (int i = height; i >= 0; --i ) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int height = 7;
for (int i = height; i>=1; i-- ) { //reverse,and change '0' to '1'
  int space_cnt = height - i;  //number of space we need
  for (int j = 1; j <= height ; j++) {
    if(space_cnt-->0){
       System.out.print(" ");      
    }else{
       System.out.print("*");
    }
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank  you so much. The code shows the shape now but I made a mistake. I drew the image wrong on the top. I have changed it now. Can you see it and tell me what I should do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the inner loop. Currently you are looping up to the current line number (= height) and in each iteration, you add one star to the current line. So it will start with one star and go up to eight stars, as your height is set to total 7.
To make it reverse, you have to reverse the inner loop, so it start with 8 stars (height - i) and go back to one:

```
for (int j = height - i; j >= 0; j--) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

Comment: Had a mistake in my code. Fixed and tested it now, so the current one will work.

Comment: Hey guys. All of your solutions worked and I highly appreciate it. However I made a stupid mistake. The picture produced should be different and i have changed it in the top. Can you please tell me how to make that?

Comment: You just need to fill up with spaces then. You could do ith with two loops. The first one adds the spaces and the second one you can keep the same. Number of spaces is obviously the height - number of stars.

Comment: I have tried that but it puts it all on the same line. I am sorry if I am being too needy, but can you please write the code.  I am extremely new to to writing java programs.

Comment: What exactly did you try? And what don't you understand?

Comment: I tried to do this:                                                                                                 for (int space = 0; space <= i - 1 ; space++) {
             System.out.print(" "); }  //I put this in the first for loop

Comment: In my opinion, this should already do the trick? What is not working? What's the output?

Answer (score 0):

Change the outer loop to `for (int i = height -1; i >= 0; i--)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int height = 7;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                if (j >= i) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
*******
 ******
  *****
   ****
    ***
     **
      *
```